# Equivalent of predict_proba of scikit-learn for ONNX C++ API

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, onnx

I have trained a classification model and I use that the ONNX format of that model in C++ to predict value as follow:

```
auto inputOnnxTensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(memoryInfo, inputValues.data(), inputValues.size(), inputDims.data(), inputDims.size());

auto outputValues = session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{ nullptr }, inputNames.data(), &inputOnnxTensor, 1, outputNames.data(), 1);
   
auto* result = outputValues[0].GetTensorMutableData<int>();
```

In Python using `predict_proba` in Scikit-learn we are able to infer the class probabilities (i.e. the probability that a particular data point falls into the underlying classes).

How can I obtain the same probability values of `predict_proba()` in C++ with ONNX format? Is there any equivalent to `predict_proba` in ONNX C++ API?

Comment: Do you have any progress with this problem? I'd appreciate any hint how to get the list of predicted probabilities.

Comment: No unfortunately, I was not able to find a way to get the probabilities

Answer (score 2):

When converting your classification model to ONNX (I assume you use **skl2onnx**), disable `ZipMap`. I'm not sure about other options, but here is my working code:

```
model = to_onnx(my_rfc_model, x_train, 
    options={'zipmap': False, 'output_class_labels': False, 'raw_scores': False})
onnx.save_model(model, "model.onnx")
```

In my case (I use RandomForestClassifier), the model contains one input and two outputs, it is by default. The first output provides the classification results and the second output provides the probabilities for each class. By disabling `ZipMap` we get probabilities serialized sequentially. For example, if you have 3 possible classes and 2 samples with class probability distributions `[[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]]`, then, when predicting using onnx runtime in C++, the probabilities will be stored in output memory sequentially: `[0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2]`.

To get probabilities, use correct output name (by default it is `probabilities`). You can find all output names using `GetOutputCount()` and `GetOutputName()`. See this example: https://github.com/leimao/ONNX-Runtime-Inference/blob/main/src/inference.cpp

Create output tensor with enough space to hold probabilities for each class:

```
std::vector<float> proba(3 * num_samples);
std::vector<Ort::Value> output_tensors;                                                         
output_tensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
memoryInfo, proba.data(), 3*num_samples, output_dims_.data(), output_dims_.size()));
```

Note that we provide room for `3 * number_of_samples` floats.

Run prediction:

```
session_->Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, input_names.data(), input_tensors.data(), 1, 
    output_names.data(), output_tensors.data(), 1);
```

In my case `output_names` declared as follows:

```
std::vector<const char*> output_names {"probabilities"};
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Setting `'zipmap': False` causes `onnxruntime.InferenceSession` to return class and probability arrays, as opposed to a list of dicts. Thanks!